# Same input gives different output for a program

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

Novice programmer here. I am trying to write a program wherein it will take UIDs from user and validate them based on certain rules. The rules are:

1. It must contain at least 2 uppercase English alphabet characters.
2. It must contain at least 3 digits ( 0-9 ).
   3.It should only contain alphanumeric characters (A -Z ,a  -z  & 0 -9 ).
3. No character should repeat.
4. There must be exactly  characters in a valid UID.

I am putting in the code. Also apologies for this big code (I am a newbie)

```
# UID Validation
n=int(input()) #for iterations
uid=[]
# char=[]
valid=1
upper=0
numeric=0

# take input first of everycase
for x in range (0,n):
    num=input()
    uid.append(num)
# print (uid)
for i in uid:
    # print (i)
    # to count each word and number
    count={}
    for char in i:
        count[char]=count.get(char,0)+1
    for j in i:
        if j.isupper():
            upper=upper+1
        elif j.isnumeric():
            numeric=numeric+1
    # print('numeric =', numeric)
    # print('upper =', upper)
        
    # Check conditions
    while valid==1: 
        if len(i)!= 10: 
            valid= 0
            # print('invalid for word count')
        elif i.isalnum()== False: #alphanumeric
            valid=0
            # print('invalid for alnum')
        elif upper<2: #minimum alphabet and numbers
            valid=0
            # print('invalid for min alphabet')
        elif numeric<3:
            valid=0
            # print('invalid for min numeric')
        else:
            for k,v in count.items(): #no repitation
                if v>1:
                    valid=0

        # to check if given UID is valid or not
        if valid==1:
            print ('Valid')
        elif valid==0:
            print('Invalid')
        valid=1
        break
```

I have written the code but it seems that I am facing problem on one input only that is to check UID tag: 2TB1YVIGNM

It is an invalid tag. My program shows the same when is I run it alone or first in a batch of many. But, Lets say I run the program and input 2 tags, with "2TB1YVIGNM" being second one, it will show is as "Valid". Mind you, this is only happening in this particular tag

There are several other tags which run fine. Some of them are mentioned here:
77yS77UXtS
d72MJ4Rerf
OA778K96P2
**2TB1YVIGN**M "EXCEPT THIS TAG"
9JC86fM1L7
3w2F84OSw5
GOeGU49JDw
8428COZZ9C
WOPOX413H2
1h5dS6K3X8
Fq6FN44C6P

The output should be:
Invalid
Valid
Invalid
**Invalid**
Valid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Valid
Invalid

My output is this:
Invalid
Valid
Invalid
**Valid**
Valid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Valid
Invalid

Comment: You aren't resetting `upper` and `numeric` back to 0 for each new uid.

Comment: If this project is not to solve the problem and is intended to be used somewhere else, I'd strongly recommend you to use regex.

Comment: I'd recommend using functions and renaming your variables, so your code gets a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to set `upper` and `numeric` back to 0 for each uid:

```py
for i in uid:
    upper = 0
    numeric = 0
    count={}
```

P.S: As for you newbie I would suggest you to read [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) it will make your code more readable and prettier

P.S.S: There is no need to count manually how many times each character meet in string, such operation already implemented in Python look at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for more details

And I agree with comment that for such type of tasks it is better to use regex

Answer (score 0):

You could extract pieces of logic into functions and call them:

```py
#It must contain at least 2 uppercase English alphabet characters.
def has_at_least_two_uppercase(potential_uid):
    return sum([char.upper() == char for char in potential_uid])>= 2

#No character should repeat.
def has_unique_chars(potential_uid):
    return len(set(potential_uid)) == len(potential_uid)

#There must be exactly characters in a valid UID.
def is_proper_length(potential_uid:str, proper_length:int = 10)-> bool:
    return len(potential_uid) == proper_length
   
#It must contain at least 3 digits ( 0-9 ).
def has_three_digits(potential_uid):
    return sum([char.isnumeric() for char in potential_uid])>=3

#It should only contain alphanumeric characters (A -Z ,a -z & 0 -9 )
# Defining a function for this may be an overkill to be honest 
def is_alphanumeric(potential_uid):
    return potential_uid.isalnum()


def is_valid_uid(potential_uid):
    if has_at_least_two_uppercase(potential_uid) is False:
        return False
    if has_unique_chars(potential_uid) is False:
        return False
    if is_proper_length(potential_uid) is False:
        return False
    if has_three_digits(potential_uid) is False:
        return False
    if is_alphanumeric(potential_uid) is False:
        return False
    return True
```

Side notes:

- use `is` to check for `True/False`
- use `True/False` and not `1/0` for boolean conditions (like `valid` variable)

[OPTIONAL / homework]

- use docstrings instead of comments
- add add type hints (see `is_proper_length` as an example)
- you can use `all()` and pass all the calls into it, but the `if`s will short circuit from the function without checking all the conditions (all depends on a problem, like number of conditions, length of the UID, number of UIDs to be checked etc.) and you can play around with order of the checks e.g. if the length is not right there's no need to check the rest (but it's a pre-optimization in a way, which is discouraged in general)
- parametrize your functions further if need be, define params for number of upper to check, numeric and so on